# Selenium Driver - How to click a value from a sub-dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I'm sort of new to Web Automation and I'm having some trouble interacting with clicking a value from a sub-dropdown.

[image: This is the special I need to add to the order]

I'm able to select the span, click the "Apply Special" link to make the drop-down appear, but no matter what I do, I can't hit the specific "li". I can get all the text from the span, but I don't know how to actually make it so it clicks the specific special.

```
    @FindBy(css = ".sub-dropdown")
    protected List<WebElement> specialsTest;

    @FindBy(id = "ctl00_ctl00_content_content_ucOrderWorkflow_upnlApplyDiscount")
    protected Element specialItems;

    public NewOrderPage addSpecificSpecialToOrder(String special) {
    Reporter.log(String.format("Add special %s to order.", special), true);
    //This clicks the Apply Special link
    specialItems.waitUntilVisible().click();

    //This prints the content of the span, just to make sure I'm hitting the right dropdown
    String text = specialsDropDown.waitElementsReady().then().getText();
    System.out.println("Dropdown getText " + text);

//This is my attempt to find the <li> text and click it, but it's not working :(
    for (WebElement li : specialsTest){
        System.out.println(li.getText());
        if (li.getText().contains(special)) {
            li.click();
            break;
        }
    }


    return this;

}
```

Any help, would be highly appreciate it. 
Thank you in advance, and let me know if I need to add more info.

Comment: Share `HTML` code.

Comment: @Citronex: Cann't you change your approach ? Rather than annotations @ findby You can simply first store a webelement till u1 and then pass an array for li tags to get them all depending upon the li size. It would be good if you can share your website so that I can show you or else try on your end. :-)

Comment: How much more HTML code you need? is the screenshot not enough?

Answer (score 1):

As I saw, the element which you are trying to click is an **a** tag ,so you need to use correct locator to point this element. We can use:

- Link/ Partiallink locator
- Xpath locator: `.//a[contains(.,'Percentage Discount')]`